# Android webview Load url doesn't work for Instagram webpage

Tags: android, webview

**I realized that not working for under android 4.3 versions.**

I have an android app which has webview. When i try to load url "http://instagram.com" it's not working It shows blank page but facebook webpage is working. 
It's really important for me please help.

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    view.loadUrl("http://www.instagram.com");
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Not showing at all? Not displayed right? Colors inverted? Phone exploded?

Comment: Hi. Yes not showing at all in my webview. Facebook and twitter are loading.

Comment: I realized that not working for under android 4.3 versions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried using the method:

> [**setDomStorageEnabled()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean));
>
> Sets whether the DOM storage API is enabled. The default value is
>   false.

for example:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("http://www.instagram.com");
```

I had previously problems loading Facebook and Twitter pages in some devices, solved using `setDomStorageEnabled()` method.

Comment: unfortunately still not loadin in my webview. After setDomStorageEnabled(true) webview began to launch browser when calling loadurl

Comment: I realized that not working for under android 4.3 versions.

Comment: so, have you tried on android 4.4 and above...? is it works with setDomStorageEnabled(); ?

Comment: I already add the above line but still it opens Chrome browser eventhough I already add it in my manifest.